# Moodle php-extension error

Tags: moodle

I have a problem with moodle. How come the errors are still there even if I have installed all the php_extensions. Attached below is the error that I have. And this is the link of my phpinfo() : http://1picto.com/info.php

I can see from my phpinfo that I have installed all the extensions but the error is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the webserver?